# SQL SERVER 2008 JOIN hints

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, join, join-hints

Recently, I was trying to optimise this query

```
UPDATE Analytics
SET UserID = x.UserID
FROM Analytics z 
INNER JOIN UserDetail x ON x.UserGUID = z.UserGUID
```

Estimated execution plan show 57% on the Table Update and 40% on a Hash Match (Aggregate). I did some snooping around and came across the topic of JOIN hints. So I added a LOOP hint to my inner join and WA-ZHAM! The new execution plan shows 38% on the Table Update and 58% on an Index Seek.

So I was about to start applying LOOP hints to all my queries until prudence got the better of me. After some googling, I realised that JOIN hints are not very well covered in [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173815.aspx). Therefore...

1. Can someone please tell me why applying LOOP hints to all my queries is a bad idea. I read somewhere that a LOOP JOIN is default JOIN method for query optimiser but couldn't verify the validity of  the statement?
2. When are JOIN hints used? When the sh*t hits the fan and ghost busters ain't in town?
3. What's the difference between LOOP, HASH and MERGE hints? BOL states that MERGE seems to be the slowest but what is the application of each hint?

Thanks for your time and help people!

I'm running SQL Server 2008 BTW. The statistics mentioned above are ESTIMATED execution plans.

Comment: Before looking into this, are your indexes and statistics up to date?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Can someone please tell me why applying LOOP hints to all my queries is a bad idea. I read somewhere that a LOOP JOIN is default JOIN method for query optimiser but couldn't verify the validity of the statement?

Because this robs the optimizer of the opportunity to consider other methods which can be more efficient.

> When are JOIN hints used? When the sh*t hits the fan and ghost busters ain't in town?

When the data distribution (on which the optimizer makes its decisions) is severely skewed and the statistics are no able to represent it correctly.

> What's the difference between LOOP, HASH and MERGE hints? BOL states that MERGE seems to be the slowest but what is the application of each hint?

These are different algorithms.

1. `LOOP` is nested loops: for each record from the outer table, the inner table is searched for matches (using the index of available). Fastest when only a tiny portion of records from both tables satisfy the `JOIN` and the `WHERE` conditions.
2. `MERGE` sorts both tables are traverses them in the sort order, skipping the unmatched records. Fastest for the `FULL JOIN`s and when both recordsets are already sorted (from previous sort operations or when the index access path is used)
3. `HASH` build a hash table in the temporary storage (memory or `tempdb`) from one of the tables and searches it for each record from the other one. Fastest if the large portion of records from either table matches the `WHERE` and `JOIN` condition.

Comment: Great explanation! I don't suppose you could give your 2 cents on what Martin's reply?

Answer (score 2):

> The Estimated execution plan show 57%
>   on the Table Update and 40% on a Hash
>   Match (Aggregate). I did some snooping
>   around and came across the topic of
>   JOIN hints. So I added a LOOP hint to
>   my inner join and WA-ZHAM! The new
>   execution plan shows 38% on the Table
>   Update and 58% on an Index Seek.

Surely that means that your proposed plan is worse? Assuming the table update takes a constant time it is now being out costed by the index activity.

Comment: Is that a fair assumption? I have always been under the impression that having the bulk of the work on Index Seek is the way to go.

Comment: I think its a fair assumption though I'm happy to stand corrected if I'm wrong. Is there a clustered index on Analytics.UserGUID? If so updating the GUID to a different value will likely cause a fair bit of IO which may explain any performance issue you are getting.

Comment: I have a non-clustered index on Analytics.UserGUID. I'm updating the UserID columns not the UserGUID. I have no indexes on the Analytics.UserID column.