# DB2 Plan table method

Tags: sql, performance, join, db2, sql-execution-plan

Which of the method value given in a plan table row is better when a join is involved in tables?

- method=1, nested loop join
- method=2, merge scan join
- method=4, hybrid join

Comment: Jens Muhlenhoff - Thank you for structuring my post.

Comment: Your question is pretty vague, you should edit it and describe what the data is (table schemas and indexes, count of rows, the sql query, etc.)

Comment: In general none of them is "better", your real question is probably "What's the difference between them?".

Comment: Related question for SQL Server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446927/sql-server-2008-join-hints

Comment: Are you talking about LUW or z? because hybrid does not exist in Z. Also, there are hash join, and in v10 Zig Zag

Comment: @AngocA: [yeah, it does](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.perf/src/tpc/db2z_hybridjoinaccess.htm)?

Comment: I understand it depends on various factors. Deviating a little from the question asked - where in the plan table can I see the overall execution time or individiual step execution time. Thanks

Comment: In answer to AngoCa - It is the Z

Comment: I typed wrong, hybrid does not exist in LUW, but in Z.

Answer (score 0):

The only "correct" answer is: it depends.

Read up on the [Information Center article on interpreting access plans](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.perf/src/tpc/db2z_plantablejoinexamples.htm) for more detail on how all the methods work.